# Strange response on calling Mesibo APIs

Tags: mesibo

I am using Mesibo SDKs on my Android app for chat and so far all my requirements are fulfilled. All of my Mesibo APIs and token information are stored on server side only. The android app fetches user token from the backend server.

Recently, my app started working unexpectedly such as chat messages not sent/received, user account not created and add group not working at Mesibo side. The backend APIs are all working fine. Upon calling one of the Mesibo API from PostMan, I got this response.

**Request:**

```
{'token':$appToken,
 'op':'groupadd',
 'name':$roomName,
 'flag':0,
 'expiry':$expiry,
 'expiryext'"$expiry,
 'active':1
}
```

**Response:**

```
{"op":"groupadd","result":false,"error":"TOKENBREACH"}
```

This error is new to me and I do not know how to resolve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOKENBREACH indicates that backend API and app token are used from multiple IP addresses which jeopardizes your app security. You are likely to be using an app token from the client-side and hence breach has been flagged.

Read here https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/backend-api/

Comment: Actually, I was using the app token and Mesibo APIs from client side before this. And I got a warning email from the Mesibo as well. After that, I completely switched back to server side mode. Now I think that is the exact cause of this problem. I wonder whether changing app token will resolve this or not.